# Angular / Firebase Authentication - Make boolean Observable from service to component?

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to change the `[hidden]` properties of some elements in my `app.component.html` file based on the 'isAuthenticated' boolean value present in the component controller, which is matched to the property of the same name defined in my `auth.service` service.

So when there is an authenticated user, and the boolean value for 'isAuthenticated' is true, the elements should show.

Currently, the boolean is set to false by default and updated where in the same `auth.service` file where it is defined upon successful login, but I need the value to update in the `app.component.ts` file as well, but can't do this due to 'Observable' not being assignable to booleans.

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

private user: Observable<firebase.User>;

isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
      this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }

signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
        .auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(value => {
            console.log('Signed In');
            this.isAuthenticated = true;
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Sign-In Error: ', err.message);
        });
}

signOut() {
    this.firebaseAuth
        .auth
        .signOut();
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    console.log('Signed Out');
}

register(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
        .auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(value => {
            console.log('Registration Successful', value);
         })
         .catch(err => {
            console.log('Registration Error: ', err.message);
        });    
}

}
```

**can-activate-route.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@Injectable()

export class CanActivateRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

canActivate (
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated;
}

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { UsersService } from './services/users.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {

isAuthenticated: boolean;
titles: any[];

constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private usersService: UsersService, public authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button mat-button (click)="signOut()" [hidden]="isAuthenticated">Sign Out</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your component (app.component.ts) from this:

```
isAuthenticated: boolean;
```

To this:

```
export class AppComponent {

   get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
       return this.authService.isAuthenticated;
   }

   titles: any[];

   constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, 
               private usersService: UsersService, 
               public authService: AuthService, 
               private router: Router) { }
}
```

That will ensure that as the service value changes, the component property will always get the most recent value.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working. Is this function intended to go inside the component in which the user logs in?

Comment: I expanded the code to make it more clear where this change is required.